# CSS Inconsistency Same css is valid in one version of my html and invalid in another

Tags: css, google-chrome, margin

I am working with code that I inherited from another developer.  My supervisor asked me why a particular div had lost the white space that it had in the previous version.  In investigating, I discovered that the margin-top property was missing it's unit[[image: version where the property is being marked as invalid]

Investigating further I looked at the same element in the previous version of the site, and to my surprise the unit was missing then but was not being invalidated by the same browser.[image: version where the property is not being marked as invalid]

As soon as I put 30px instead of just 30 my version of the site conformed with expectations, but I am very confused by this seeming inconsistency. Can anyone shed any light on this?  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In looking into this further, I discovered the cause.  My predecessor had omitted the  header and thus the browser was operating in quirks mode.  Apparently in quirks mode the unit is optional.